# Structure array changes size when passed to a reduction function in the parfor loop Matlab?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, parfor

I  ran into a weird problem when I used structure arrays inside a `parfor` loop. Below is my main function:

```
comm_struct=struct('field1',0,'field2',zeros(10,1),'field3',sparse(zeros(10,10)));
a(1:100,1)=comm_struct;
b(1:10,1)=comm_struct;
disp(size(b))
parfor ct=1:12
        b=max_select_2(b,a);
end
```

where `max_select_2` is

```
function y=max_select_2(b,a)
if size(b,1)~=10
    error('size of b is not 10 but %d',size(b,1)),
end
d(1:110,1)=struct('field1',0,'field2',zeros(10,1),'field3',sparse(zeros(10,10)));
d(1:10,1)=b;
d(11:110,1)=a;
[~,sort_idx]=sort([d.field1],'descend');
y=d(sort_idx(1:10));
```

If I replace the `parfor` with |for| and ran on my local matlab, no problem, but if I use `parfor` and run this on a cluster the output is
10 1
which is expected but I also got the error message
`"size of b is not 10 but 100"`
which means for some reason when `b` is passed to the function `max_select_2`, its size changed from 10 to 100? I doubt that it has something to do with how matlab handles the structure array but I don't really know what's going on and how to fix it...

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Li

Comment: You can't parallelise that loop because `b` is modified at each iteration and then re-used, but in a parallel loop the iterations are independent. `parfor` loops don't like the results of one iteration affecting another iteration, because the order of iterations being run is not sequential.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment, David, but I don't think `b` being modified every iteration is a problem because `b` is a reduction variable here. If `b` is an array, the code runs without any problem and I get expected results. That's why I was suspecting that it has something to do with how Matlab handles the structure array.

Answer (score 0):

The accumulation function you are using is not allowed [(reference)](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/reduction-variables.html:)

> Unless f is a known noncommutative built-in, it is assumed to be commutative. There is currently no way to specify a user-defined, noncommutative function in parfor.

From my understanding of your code, I recommend to use `;` (concatenate) to accumulate and sort outside the parfor loop. Another alternative would be a sliced matrix where each iteration is allowed to fill one column of 10 elements, finally sorting and reshaping it to a vector outside the loop.